# How to best compute the maximum value of a multivariable function?

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, maximum

I'm new to Mathematica. I have the function:

```
f[x_,y_] =  a1 (1 - (b1/(b1 + c f1 x))^(r1/r2)) + 
 a3 (1 - (b3/(b3 + c f3 (1 - x - y)))^(r5/r6)) + 
 a2 (1 - (b2/(b2 + c f2 y))^(r3/r4))
```

[image]

The unknowns are x and y, where the rest (a1, a2, ..., b1, ... ) are known variables, greater than 0, in the domain of Real numbers. I need a way to find x and y, for which (given we know the other variables) `f(x,y)` will have the maximum value. When I use the function `maximize` it takes forever to compute or sometimes it won't even execute. Finding derivatives works but then I need to express x and y in terms of the known variables, however using `solve` for solving the system of dfdx and dfdy yet again takes forever or doesn't execute at all. Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Here is the code I used:

for Maximize:

```
Maximize[a1*(1 - (b1/(b1 + c*x*f1))^r1) + 
a2*(1 - (b2/(b2 + c*y*f2))^r2) + 
a3*(1 - (b3/(b3 + c*(1 - x - y)*f3))^r3), {x, y}]
```

for derivative:

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 a1*(1 - (b1 / (b1 + c*x*f1))^r1) + a2*(1 - (b2 / (b2 + c*y*f2))^r2) + 
 a3*(1 - (b3 / (b3 + c*(1 - x - y)*f3))^r3);
dfdx = D[f[x, y], x];
dfdy = D[f[x, y], y];
Solve[dfdx == 0 && dfdy == 0 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && a1>0 && 
 a2>0 && a3>0 && b1>0 && b2>0 && b3>0 && c>0 && f1>0 && f2>0 && f3>0 
 && r1>0 && r2>0 && r3>0, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Did you define the function using f[x_,y_] (square brackets)? Your code has parentheses instead. Can you show us the EXACT code you ran?

Comment: @MarcoB Apologies, I used square brackets. Updated the question with the exact code.

Comment: Your function is complex in general, but according to the documentation "Maximize requires that all functions present in the input be real-valued".